# Android 5.0 is not supporting for lower versions

Tags: android, eclipse

Please help me.
I got struck in solving this error for more than 3 days

I didnot get the proper solution.
I have updated my eclipse to run android 5.0.

I had created a simple android application using minimum version 16 and target version 21 to run android 5.0 material theme.
Have added the theme in **styles.xml** as like this

```
    <resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
    </resources>
```

I followed the link to add supporting libraries appcompatv7. 
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7

But I am getting error stating that **R cannot be resolved to variable**
 whenever I add this appcompat to my project.
please give me a suggestions and also please share your android 5.0 running in lower version project.

Answer (score 1):

for api lower than 21 use Theme.AppCompat instead of android:Theme.Material

please read here http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

read [**compatibility**](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) for material theme and  add **appcompat** into your project as library that you can find in

`sdk\extras\android\compatibility\v7\appcompat`
than

your style.xml

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **theme.xml** should be something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey_main</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/grey_main</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your mainactivity.java. 
your r.java file could have not generated so that you might get error mentioning R cannot be Resolved

Must add Add appcompat into your project library

```
sdk\extras\android\compatibility\v7\appcompat
```

Add AppBaseTheme

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```